# Azure Powershell New-AzSynapseManagedPrivateEndpoint Definition File format?

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network, azure-synapse

I'm trying to deploy a managed private endpoint to my synapse instance to connect it to a key Vault in the same resource Group. The documentation for the same deployment in Bicep is very incomplete so I thought to try my luck with PowerShell using the following command :

```
    New-AzSynapseManagedPrivateEndpoint `
   -WorkspaceName "synapse-test-joao" `
   -Name "managedPrivateEndpointKeyVault" `
   -DefinitionFile file.json
```

However, I cannot seem to find the format for the definition file anywhere on the internet, so was wondering if anyone had any information regarding the json format and what parameters need to go inside.
This would be immensely helpful,
Joao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The sample `-DefinitionFile` should be in below format:

```json
{
    # here i am using sample blob storage
    "name": "testblob", #ManagePrivate Endpoint Name
    "properties": {
        "privateLinkResourceId": "/subscriptions/<subscription ID>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroup name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<Storage Account Name>",
        "groupId": "blob"
    }
}
```

#### To get the `-DefinitionFile` Sample file to follow the below ways:

#### Way 1:

- Go to your **Azure Synapse Workspace -> Managed Private Endpoints**
- Drag your cursor into your private endpoint you can see **{} - (Code)** from there you can get the sample `-DefinitionFile`.

[image]

#### Way 2:

This way you can get the **PrivateLinkResourceId** of **ManagedPrivateEndpoint**

```
$ds = Get-AzSynapseWorkspace -Name <Synapse workspaces Name> 
$ws | Get-AzSynapseManagedPrivateEndpoint -Name <Your Created Managed Private Endpoint Name>
```

```
# Private Link Resource Id
/subscriptions/<subscription ID>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroup name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<Storage Account Name>
```

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/data-plane/managed-private-endpoints/create#create-a-managed-private-endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

The code to deploy the managed private endpoint for Synapse in a devOps pipeline can be as follows:

```
param(
    $environment,
    $synapseWorkspaceVar,
    $subscriptionId,
    $resourceGroupNameVar,
    $keyVaultNameVar
)

$createPrivateEndpointJsonString = @"
{    
    "properties": {
        "privateLinkResourceId": "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupNameVar/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/$keyVaultNameVar",
        "groupId": "vault"
    }
}
"@


write-output $createPrivateEndpointJsonString

$tempFolderPath = ".\temp"

if (!(Test-path -path $tempFolderPath)) { 
    echo "new file"
    New-Item -ItemType directory -path $tempFolderPath
}

write-output "creating the PrivateEndpoint Definition Json file...."
$jsonpath = ".\$tempFolderPath\createprivateendpoint.json"

Set-Content -Path $jsonpath -value $createPrivateEndpointJsonString

echo "Creating new Managed Private Endpoint from Synapse to KeyVault..."
New-AzSynapseManagedPrivateEndpoint `
-WorkspaceName $synapseWorkspaceVar `
-Name "managedPrivateEndpointKeyVaultACEP" `
-DefinitionFile $jsonpath
    
Get-AzSynapseManagedPrivateEndpoint -WorkspaceName $synapseWorkspaceVar
```